# Drifting dust, and ice near the ground

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms

Sometimes, when there is moderately strong gusting wind, one can see the wind raising a little dust just a little above the ground, from the ankle height, up to a few meters. When the wind gust is gone, the dust goes back on the ground. Sometimes a small vortex of dust is formed, sometimes, they are just blankets of dust.

What are these kind of dust clouds called? Is there a different name when dust is mixed with ice, or frozen snow, or when it's just frozen snow?

Comment: I don't think frozen snow lifts so easily -- I think it's too heavy and solidified. / In the weather report they talk about *blowing snow* -- does that work for you?

Comment: @aparente001 Snow can freeze in many ways. Where I live, it happens quite often that the wind raises an ice dust and dumps it near fences or houses. What I was thinking of I've seen a lot on the road, when it's very cold and dry.

Comment: Magicsowon - And I thought winter was yucky here.

Answer (score 1):

The whirling vortex (visible because of the dust raised) is sometimes called a

> **dust devil**
>
> A small whirlwind or air vortex over land, visible as a column of dust and debris.
>
> *the wind kicked up dust devils in the street*

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/dust_devil)

Comment: It could also be an *eddy.*

Comment: @aparente001 true, but *eddy* applies to water too. *Dust devil* is specific to a vortex of wind. Apparently in Australia it is called a [willy-willy](https://www.lexico.com/definition/willy-willy), and in Ireland a [fairy wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dust_devil#Alternate_names).

Comment: Hopefully the context will show that it's too dry or cold for a water eddy.

Comment: When is the ocean too dry for an eddy?